# Highlight words in a docx file and display in which line they appear and how many times in each, read 2 docx in python

Tags: python

My python program should read 2 files
one file with the words to search
and another file which is were the program should look up for the words.

I already found how to open one file, but cannot make that the program look up for the words from the 1st file

```
import sys

print('\n\n')
print('Name of file is be analyse ?')
infile_name = input()

#  Opening files for READ in Python.
infile_name = './archivos/poemas.txt'
print('\nName of file is be analyse : ', infile_name)
infile  = open(infile_name, 'r');

#  Opening files for WRITE in Python.
outfile_name = infile_name[:-4] + '_review.html'
print('Results in file:             ', outfile_name)
outfile = open(outfile_name, 'w');


linea_out = "<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE> Final Project </TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n\n"
outfile.write(linea_out)
linea_out = "<BODY  BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\"  
BACKGROUND=\"./images/ITESMwatermark.png\">\n<BR><P>\n<BR><P>\n\n\n\n\n"
outfile.write(linea_out)
outfile.writelines(['<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE> Final Project 
</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n\n',
                '<BODY  BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\"  
BACKGROUND=\"./images/ITESMwatermark.png\">\n<BR><P>\n<BR><P>\n\n\n\n\n'])


i = 1
with infile:
    for linea in infile:
        if len(str(i)) == 1:
            dm1 = '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;'
        elif len(str(i)) == 2:
            dm1 = '&nbsp; &nbsp;'
        elif len(str(i)) == 3:
            dm1 = '&nbsp;'


        if  i % 8 == 0:
            linea = '<b>' + linea + '</b>'
        elif i % 4 == 0:
            linea = "<span style=\"background-color: #FFFF00\"><b><font         
color=\"red\">" + linea + "</font></b></span>"

        linea_out = 'linea: ' + dm1 + str(i) + '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
&nbsp;' + linea + '<BR>\n';
        outfile.write(linea_out)
        i += 1


linea_out = "\n\n<BR><P></BODY></HTML>"
outfile.write(linea_out)
outfile.close()
infile.close();
print("\n\n")
```

I expect for it to return another docx file with the highlighted words and in which line and how many times it appears.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try? Any research? SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: Yess, I've already made progress, the answer down below has helped me a lot, I'm just figuring out how to return the file

Answer (score 0):

You first need to open the file with look-up words in addition to the text file for (searching the words) that you have already open.
Go through each look up word and each line of the text. For each word go through all the lines. Store a hashmap with keys as look-up words and in the value list of line numbers. Now you open output file and write the word from map and line numbers and length of the list of line numbers.
It's not that efficient though.

Comment: Thank youu i Think i have figured it out, I made it to read a txt file, and then it to make it a list, and then to highlight the words from the list